# Why do we require aperiodicity in MCMC?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

According to the Ergodic Theorem by Birkhoff, for any measure-preserving dynamical system $(X, \cal{A},\mu ,\bf{T})$ and any $\mu$-integrable integrable function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$, the ergodic average $\frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{k=0}^{N}{f({\bf{T}}^{(k)}(x)}) \to \mathbb{E}_{\pi}[f]$ for $\mu$-almost every $x$. A Markov Measure on a finite state space is ergodic iff the associated chain is irreducible. However, almost every MCMC algorithm I come across additionally specifies the requirement of aperiodicity, which is necessary for convergence of the distribution to the the steady state. Why is this done? Are there any additional advantages to requiring aperiodicity?

Comment: Which MCMC "algorithms" are you referring to? The ones which *produce* random values (ie RNGs) , or the ones which are generated *from* random values (bootstrap, Gibbs sampling, etc.)?

Comment: I'm mainly studying Metropolis-Hastings at the moment, but the question really is about the entire approach of MCMC. If our aim is to estimate an integral, written as an expectation over some distribution, then isn't Birkhoff's ergodic theorem sufficient?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, aperiodicity is simply a requirement for RNGs since (if you view it as a dynamical system) if there's periodicity, it's not random. Many of the tests for (quasi) RNGs essentially look for periods. That's not to say that deterministic output can't be used for integration/optimization (and in some cases it is, i.e. grid search or rainbow table crytographs). The jackknife and bootstrap, for instance, are both algorithms consistent for estimating the same SE, but jackknife is deterministic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aperiodicity or the absence thereof is a minor nuisance: when a chain is periodic, it does not converge to the stationary distribution, strictly speaking. This does not prevent Birkhoff's ergodic theorem to apply of course and most Monte Carlo applications of the MCMC principle still apply.

Furthermore, periodicity can be avoided by looking at the skeleton kernel
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon^{i-1} K^i\qquad\varepsilon>0$$
which consists in subsampling randomly the Markov sequence at a Geometric rate.

Comment: Periodic Markov chains may converge for some initial distributions. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033722/periodic-markov-chains.